# Why config file of vi is not named .virc but .exrc?

Tags: vi

Just from curiosity I want to know why .exrc is not named .virc?
Is there reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/vi.html

> The vi (visual) utility is a screen-oriented text editor. The user can
>   switch back and forth between vi and the line editor ex and execute ex
>   commands from within vi.

So, mainly due to its historical relationship to `ex`. If you use a modern `vi` variant like `vim`, then you'd be using `.vimrc`.

Comment: So there was/is a ex editor. Thanks jjlin!